# Clockwork and Chivalry first versus second edition: setting and background

Tags: campaign-settings, clockwork-and-chivalry

Which edition of [Clockwork and Chivalry](http://www.clockworkandchivalry.co.uk/) has more setting and background material?

I run systemless games, thus I am not interested in which edition contains the "better" version of the rule set. However, I am interested in the background material of the game.

**Edit**: If somebody has one edition but not the other, I would still be interested in how much background/setting to rules there is in said edition. I am loathed to ask for a metric such as a ratio of pages of rules to pages of setting since that could be misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2nd Edition has more setting/background material, although there is plenty in the 1st edition too. The 2nd edition incorporates a lot of setting info from the Divers and Sundry sourcebook, as well as some fresh material. The Renaissance Deluxe ruleset also provides some more generic setting material for the age of black powder.

Comment: Welcome to the site and +1 for a good answer. BTW, are you one of the designers of Clockwork & Chivalry?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Yes, I'm one of the designers.

Comment: Welcome! glad to a have a designer aboard. In this case please either edit or add a comment instead of adding a new answer. We try to keep things clean here. Again welcome! (originally from @waxeagle)

Comment: Whoops, hadn't worked out the protocol - noted, and thanks for the welcome :)